# Setup ANTLR 4 grammar to handle Java and C# environments

Tags: java, c#, antlr, grammar

I'm using an ANTLR 4 split grammar both in both C# and Java environments and I am unable to compile the grammar in both languages unless I change the function NotifyErrorListeners to use camel case notifyErrorListeners.

C# example:

```
statement       
:   expression SEMICOLON
|   { NotifyErrorListeners("; expected."); } expression // They forgot the semicolon.
```

Java example:

```
statement       
:   expression SEMICOLON
|   { notifyErrorListeners("; expected."); } expression // They forgot the semicolon.
```

My C# ANTLR environment was pulled through Nuget: Antlr4 4.2.2-alpha001

My Java ANTLR environment was downloaded from antlr.org: antlr-4.5-complete.jar

Is there a way I could modify my grammar so I do not have to modify it when switching between languages? Is there a better function to use that would facilitate both environments?

Comment: C# has a preprocessor - can it be used here? (I've never seen antlr in C#, so pardon my ignorance.)

Comment: I could use the C# preprocessor, but in my limited experience with java I can't find a way to make it compatible with both. The goal is to make the grammar compile in both environments without changes to the grammar itself.

Comment: For compiling C# you need a `#define NotifyErrorListeners notifyErrorListeners`, if the grammar is written to fit Java.

Comment: As far as I know, C# cannot define macros using #define. It is limited to defining tokens like DEBUG and such for use in #if blocks. Am I missing the point?

Comment: No. I just thought it might be possible. - Using the C preprocessor might be an option. - But what about defining a static method as a wrapper? If it isn't used in Java, it doesn't hurt. - Finally: why do you need this in two languages? Java should be available where C# is.

Comment: @laune The script parser is being primarily used by a large C# application so I'm pretty set on using the C# environment primarily. However, there are nice free utilities like [ANTLRWorks 2](http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/antlrworks), but they are written using the Java environment. The grammar being able to support both is a huge help for me when debugging problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Create a partial class in the C# project for the Parser and make sure it is in the same assembly and namespace. Then it is easy to add a method that uses the camel casing Java is expecting. Now I can use both environments without modifying my grammar.

```
public partial class ScriptParser
{
    public void notifyErrorListeners(string message)
    {
        this.NotifyErrorListeners(message);
    }
}
```

Thank you laune for the questions and suggestions. You pushed me towards to the correct answer.